# Issues using ncdc function of rnoaa

Tags: r, date, time, download, rnoaa

I am using the `ncdc`  function from `rnoaa` package of R to download rainfall data for one station

This is the code:

```
start_date <- "1895-01-01"
end_date <- "1895-12-31"
datatype <- "PRCP"
siteNumber <- "GHCND:USC00023498"
data <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid=siteNumber[j], datatypeid=datatype, startdate = start_date, enddate = end_date)$data
```

I have checked and this station has data until 1895-07-31, but the output I got is only until 1895-01-25:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(date = c("1895-01-01T00:00:00", "1895-01-02T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-03T00:00:00", "1895-01-04T00:00:00", "1895-01-05T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-06T00:00:00", "1895-01-07T00:00:00", "1895-01-08T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-09T00:00:00", "1895-01-10T00:00:00", "1895-01-11T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-12T00:00:00", "1895-01-13T00:00:00", "1895-01-14T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-15T00:00:00", "1895-01-16T00:00:00", "1895-01-17T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-18T00:00:00", "1895-01-19T00:00:00", "1895-01-20T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-21T00:00:00", "1895-01-22T00:00:00", "1895-01-23T00:00:00", 
"1895-01-24T00:00:00", "1895-01-25T00:00:00"), datatype = c("PRCP", 
"PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", 
"PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", 
"PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP"
), station = c("GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", "GHCND:USC00023498", 
"GHCND:USC00023498"), value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 56L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 94L, 76L, 102L, 0L, 0L, 137L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fl_m = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
), fl_q = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), fl_so = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), fl_t = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have also tried with other years and I have the same issue, only data for the first month is downloaded.

Is there any issue with my code? (I used this function on other occasions and was working properly)

Comment: You need to adjust the limit option in the `ncdc` call.  From the help: "Defaults to 25, limits the number of results in the response. Maximum is 1000 (optional)"